# Call a function without its parameters

Tags: php

Below are the functions that am using to make reusable pagination. If you see the code below, theirs a function

> generate_pages()

which is taking parameters from function

> paged_controls()

But I would like to call the function generate_pages() without passing any parameters on body.php.

This is the error message am getting on body.php when calling function

> generate_pages()

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for generate_pages(), called in 
E:\admin\snippets\body.php on line 11 and defined in 
E:\admin\cores\pages.php on line 12
```

Notice: Undefined variable: limit in E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\hoplate\admin\cores\pages.php on line 16

Is that possible?

**pages.php**

```
<?php
        function page_count(){
            global $db;
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(pages_id) FROM pages";
            $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
            $rows = $db->FETCH_ROW();
            foreach($rows as $row){
                return $row[0];
            }
        }

        function generate_pages($limit){

            /* Run actual query now to get the records from database */
                global $db;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages " . $limit;
                $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
                return $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();
        }

        function paged_controls($page_rows = 1){
                global $db;
            /* Call the function page_count to get the total page count */
                $row_count = page_count();
            /* We use the ceil function to round the number to whole number */
                $last = ceil($row_count / $page_rows);
            /* Make sure that the last page cannot be less then 1 */
                if($last < 1){
                    $last = 1;
                }
            /* Est. the page number variables */
                $pagenum = 1;
            /* Set the pagenum variables from URL else set it to 1*/
                if(isset($_GET["paged"])){
                    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET["paged"]);
                }
            /* Make sure page number canoot be less then 1 */
                if($pagenum < 1){
                    $pagenum = 1;
                } else if($pagenum > $last){
                    $pagenum = $last;
                }

            /* Set the range of query to be excuted depend on our variables values set*/
                $limit = 'LIMIT '.($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows . ','. $page_rows;

                generate_pages($limit);

            $paged_controls = "";

            /* Only if theirs more then 1 page of results */
            if($last != 1){
                if($pagenum > 1){
                    $previous = $pagenum - 1;
                    $paged_controls .= '<a href="?paged='.$previous.'">Previous</a>&nbsp;';

                    /* Renders the left paged numbers */
                    for($i = $pagenum - 4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
                        if($i > 0){
                            $paged_controls .= '<a href="?paged='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>&nbsp;';
                        }
                    }
                }

                /* Render the current page the user is at */
                $paged_controls .= ''.$pagenum.'&nbsp;';

                /* Renders the right paged numbers */
                for($i = $pagenum + 1; $i <= $last; $i++){
                    $paged_controls .= '<a href="?paged='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>&nbsp;';
                    if($i >= $pagenum + 4){
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if($pagenum != $last){
                    $next = $pagenum + 1;
                    $paged_controls .= '<a href="?paged='.$next.'">Next</a>&nbsp;';
                }
                return $paged_controls;
            }           
        }
    ?>
```

**body.php**

```
<?php 
$pages = generate_pages(); 
  foreach($pages as $page){
    echo $pages_id = $page->pages_id . "<br/>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you don't pass a parameter how will the query run ?

Comment: Add a default value like the `page_controls` method has?

Answer (score 2):

Only way I would see this working is adding a check.

```
function generate_pages($limit = null){
/* Run actual query now to get the records from database */
    $gloab $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages " . isset($limit) ? "LIMIT $limit" : "";
    $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
    return $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();   
}
```

So now it could be run one of two ways

```
generate_pages();
```

or:

```
generate_pages(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare both of your function headers:

```
function generate_pages($limit)
function paged_controls($page_rows = 1)
```

PHP offers you [to specify default arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php), just like C++ (you have to scroll down a bit to see the section).
Your `paged_controls`-function already does this and it is a great way of achieving what you want without editing the business logic within the function.

A default argument kicks in whenever you call a function without any parameters.

So, if you edit

```
function generate_pages($limit)
```

to (for example)

```
function generate_pages($limit = 'LIMIT 0,18446744073709551615')
```

and call the function via `generate_pages()`, PHP will automatically assume `$limit = 'LIMIT 0,18446744073709551615'`.
In this specific case, calling `generate_pages` without a parameter will retrieve all entries in the table you select from, as we tell the database to give us `18446744073709551615` entries from the beginning.
See the [MYSQL manual on select/limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).